# I write an sparksql UDF with java but it seems that something goes wrong

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

the whole dependency for my project is as below code:

```
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-hive_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

I want use the `UDF` to calculate the time interval between the two input date string with the format 'yyyy-mm-ss HH:mm:ss.SSS'(Example,'2017-12-26 00:00:02.044'), the result will be double with the precision to milliseconds, for example, When I pass "2017-12-26 00:00:02.044", "2017-12-26 00:00:03.045" to the `UDF` the result will be 1.001 seconds then come with the java code snippet:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.apache.spark.sql.api.java.UDF2;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class DateDistance implements UDF2<String,String,Double> {

    public Double call(String s, String s2) throws Exception {
        Double result=0D;
        if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(s)&&StringUtils.isNotBlank(s2)){
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-ss HH:mm:ss.SSS");
            Date parse = sdf.parse(s);
            Date parse2=sdf.parse(s2);
            Long milisecond1= parse.getTime();
            Long milisecond2= parse2.getTime();
            Long abs = Math.abs(milisecond1 - milisecond2);
            result = (abs.doubleValue()) / 1000D;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

The steps to use the `UDF` are as below:

1. add jar /home/hulk/learning/datedistance-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
2. create temporary function tmp_date_distance as 'com.test.datedistance.DateDistance'
3. test the UDF with the sql:

> ```
> Select tmp_date_distance('2017-12-26 00:00:02.044','2017-12-26
> 00:00:03.045') from stg.car_fact_order where dt='2018-01-09' limit 1;
> ```

All after that, I got the tips below:

```
Error in query: No handler for Hive UDF 'com.sqyc.datedistance.DateDistance'; line 1 pos 7
```

Can you please give me some advices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second step is incorrect:

> create temporary function tmp_date_distance as 'com.test.datedistance.DateDistance'

Spark UDFs are not Hive compatible and should be registered with

```
sqlContext.udf().register(name, object, type);
```

or (2.0 or later):

```
spark.udf().register(name, object, type);
```

But you don't need udf:

```
SELECT ABS(
       CAST(CAST('2017-12-26 00:00:02.044' AS TIMESTAMP) AS DOUBLE) - 
       CAST(CAST('2017-12-26 00:00:03.045' AS TIMESTAMP) AS DOUBLE) ) AS diff

+-----------------+
|             diff|
+-----------------+
|1.001000165939331|
+-----------------+
```

or rounded:

```
SELECT ROUND(ABS(
       CAST(CAST('2017-12-26 00:00:02.044' AS TIMESTAMP) AS DOUBLE) - 
       CAST(CAST('2017-12-26 00:00:03.045' AS TIMESTAMP) AS DOUBLE)), 3) AS diff

+-----+
| diff|
+-----+
|1.001|
+-----+
```

Comment: i've tried all the method you have list above, they are all work well. thanks very much.

Comment: If the syntax `CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION ...` is not valid Spark SQL, then why is it provided, and why does the SQL processor succeed executing the statement? Is there some other valid use of CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION that would achieve the above without requiring the user to compile a spark/scala app or use the pyspark api? 

Some things are easier in SQL (think of the compile/deploy steps you can skip...), but only when it _works_.